# How can I allow a user to use a password to login via SFTP, rather than a private key?

Tags: unix, ubuntu, ftp, amazon-ec2, sftp

I've setup VSFTPD in Ubuntu, and if I try to SFTP a file using a private key, I can get in fine--but I want to allow other users to use a password. [I've followed Ubuntu's instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/ftp-server.html), and already created users in an "sftponly" user group, and created the appropriate home directories but when I try to connect, I get a denied:

`Permission denied (publickey).`

When I do a ssh -vvv someuser@123.45.67.89, one line says:

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey`

I've got another server where the password method works fine, and that particular debug line says:

`debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password`

So, my question is: How can I add `password` to the list of authentication methods?

Comment: It'd sure be great to give suggestions to new users rather than downvoting them. How do you expect to foster a sense of welcome and community if you just downvote with no explanations on how to make things better? Geez.

Comment: JennyDanger:  Maybe someone meant to suggest that this question would be more on topic at superuser.com, another StackExchange site. SuperUser is generally suited to computer administration questions, while StackOverflow focuses on programming questions.

Comment: I will +1 that, thank you for explaining. I just think we should all be a little better about building this amazing community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit sshd_config and make sure you have the line `PasswordAuthentication yes`.

On Ubuntu the file is here:  /etc/ssh/ssh_config

You may want to back up a copy and change the permissions so that the backup is read-only, just in case you need to restore earlier settings.

The first answer to this question should help: https://serverfault.com/questions/154957/set-up-sftp-to-use-password-but-ssh-not-to-use-password